# React - Should we check if component is mounted before updating state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

On unmountable components, is it necessary to confirm that the component is mounted before updating the state?

I mean, is this code OK?

```
function UnmountableScreen() {
   const isMounted = useIsMounted();

   const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);

   const handleOnRefresh = async () => {
      if(!isMounted()) return;

      setIsRefreshing(true);

      await asyncOperation();

      if(!isMounted()) return; // The component might be unmounted...

      setIsRefreshing(true);
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have an actual minimal example of the use case? It might be a XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

Deducing from the function name `handleOnRefresh` must be attached to a component

```
<Button onClick={handleOnRefresh} label="..."/>
```

`UnmountableScreen` must be mounted in order to render the above component, therefore those checks are meaningless.

Comment: But, what if the async operation takes 10 secs. and the screen has been closed before it finishes?

Comment: It doesn't matter because either way, you can't change state on unmounted component, you await for the async call, if the component unmounted till then the check afterwards is pointless